# Can natural quotient map between Banach spaces be closed?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $M$ be closed subspace of X, and let $q:X\to X/M$ be the natural quotient map.

I know that $q$ is an open map. I wish to find an example of $X$ and $M$ such that $q$ is a closed map. Do such $X$ and $M$ even exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider projection $q : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $(x, y) \to x$, and the closed subset

$$G = \left\{(x, y) : y \ge \frac 1 x, x > 0\right\}$$

This should suggest how to proceed in the general case.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't see how to use the example to proceed in the general case. What I know is that the above closed $G$ is map into a non-closed set. But how to find $X$ and $M$ such that $q$ maps closed set into closed set?

Comment: @digiboy1 The above idea can be used to show that $q$ is not closed unless $M = 0$ or $M = X$.